# IIS7 URL rewrite error

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

This is my url: http://www.domain.com/advertenties/advertentie-delen/?id=23&t=1&url=ad-placed-for-simons-company-by-me

With the rewrite rule below I get this error: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred"

```
<rule name="share ad">
<match url="^advertenties/advertentie-delen?/?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="share_email.aspx?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: View your app with a browser on your server and see the detailed error it is giving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It says this "id={R:1}",which means it expects a variable on the match url tag. Since there was no variable it throws an error, this is what I have now:

```
    <rule name="share ad">
<match url="^advertenties/advertentie-delen?/?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="share_email.aspx" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```